# Fast user switching mutes my volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Each time I log in to Ubuntu 14.04, using fast user switching, my volume gets reset to about 10% and muted. I have to unmute and slide the volume control back to where I want it. This even happens if I just select "switch user," but then log back in as myself, without actually switching users.

I put this in my `~/.profile` file:

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 50% unmute
```

It sets the volume correctly upon logging out and back in, but will not prevent it from muting when switching users.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, i suggest you put that line into your `.bashrc`. The only problem is that it will run every time you open up a terminal.

Comment: No joy; same behavior. Only I seem to have this problem. When I User switch to my daughter's account, her volume is fine. But switching back to mine, it is inevitably muted. (But again, not when I log out and log in; only when I use fast user switching.)

I'm running Gnome (Metacity), btw. What's different between user switching and logging in?

Comment: I suppose it is a bit like in windows: logging out shuts your session down for good, while switching users does not, so `.profile` doesn't get sourced when returing without logging out, because it already is. It may very well be a problem concerning multiple users accessing to the audio peripherals at the same time, as some of the processes owned by your user are still running when switching.

Comment: But what would cause one user's (mine) audio to get muted, but not another's?

Comment: The fact that another user is now using the audio peripherals, in fact, i think that you can reproduce the problem by logging in your daughter's account then switching to yours, then to hers: audio would be momentarily muted if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I guess I was mistaken. It also mutes the her volume when we fast switch. (I guess she was actually logged out before, when I tested.)

So fast user switching between logged in users always mutes the volume. Is that behavior fixable?